# What is the status of TLS snap start?

Tags: tls

[TLS snap start](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-agl-tls-snapstart-00) is an extension to TLS that allows one to use 0-RTT handshakes with TLS. The draft was created on June 2010 and expired in December 2010. I don't see any updates to the draft since. Is any work being done to convert it to a standard?

Also, is anyone using TLS snap start in production (presumably Google does, but I can't find much info about this). Is there any open source implementation of TLS snap start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I asked Adam Langley, author of the snap start draft. He mentioned that they are no longer working on snap start. Instead, he referred me to [QUIC](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1g5nIXAIkN_Y-7XJW5K45IblHd_L2f5LTaDUDwvZ5L6g/edit); snap start's design is the basis of QUIC's crypto support.